# How to pass a C#.net Dictionary to VBA

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I am trying to pass a Dictionary from c# to vba but this error occurs

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))'
```

I also tried converting my list of string into vb collection but the same error occurs. 
here are my codes

```
private void btn_macrorunner_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> xlist_dictvb = new Dictionary<string, string>();
//xlist_names has been properly initialized and already has some items
    xlist_names.ForEach(x => xlist_dictvb.Add(x, x));

    ExcelFire(xlist_dictvb);
}

private void ExcelFire(Dictionary<string, string> pcoll = null)
{
    //~~> Define your Excel Objects
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;

    //~~> Start Excel and open the workbook.
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\Hutanginamo\Documents\xlkalat\0928ExcelFile.xlsm");

    if(pcoll != null)
    {
        //calls Sub ShowDict(pdict1 As Dictionary) 
        xlApp.Run("ShowDict", pcoll); //WHERE ERROR OCCURS
    }

    //~~> Clean-up: Close the workbook
    xlWorkBook.Close(false);

    //~~> Quit the Excel Application
    xlApp.Quit();

    //~~> Clean Up
    ReleaseObject(xlApp);
    ReleaseObject(xlWorkBook);
}
```

here are my vba codes

```
Sub ShowDict(pdict1 As Dictionary)
   Dim x As Variant

   For Each x In pdict1.keys
        MsgBox (pdict1.Item(x))
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What library is `Dictionary` coming from? If that's a `Scripting.Dictionary`, you're trying to pass a wildly different `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>`, a generic type, through COM interop - except you can't do that, AFAIK generic types can't be exposed to COM; you need to use a non-generic data type that's `[ComVisible(true)]`. Read up on [tag:com-interop] ;-)

Comment: in c#, i imported using System.Collections.Generic so i am using System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary, then i am trying to pass that dictionary to my VBA Sub ShowDict(pdict1 As Dictionary)

Comment: You can't use generics

Comment: can you give me an example on how to do it?

Comment: [something like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16600858/1188513)

Comment: i honestly dont understand it. can you do a step by step on how to pass a dictionary from c# to vba and put it in the answer?

Comment: **You can't** pass a `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>` from C# to VBA. Declare `pdict1 As Object` instead of `As Dictionary` (and expect another error message), or make a COM-visible, non-generic, public class with a public parameterless constructor. There's plenty of examples on this site already ;-)

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you want, you have to pass the right dictionary. `C#` dictionary can't be used in `VBA` like this. The easiest way to achieve what you want is to use `VBA` dictionary in `C#` and then pass that.

See this example.

**C# Code**

```
Scripting.Dictionary dict = new Scripting.Dictionary();
dict.Add("Apples", 50);
dict.Add("Oranges", 60);

Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;

// ~~> Opens an existing Workbook. Change path and filename as applicable
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Sample.xlsm");

// ~~> Display Excel
xlApp.Visible = true;
xlApp.Run("ShowDict", dict);
```

**VBA Code**

```
Sub ShowDict(pdict1 As Dictionary)
   Dim x As Variant

   For Each x In pdict1.keys
        MsgBox (pdict1.Item(x))
   Next
End Sub
```

**References in C#**

[image]

**References in VBA**

[image]

Comment: seems neat. i am almost done, but i am a newbie in vba, when i run the program, this error occured "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Cannot run the macro 'ShowDict'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.'"

Comment: `1` Ensure that you have pasted that macro in the module `2` Ensure you use my code as it is `3` Ensure you have set the references as mentioned above. `The above code is tried and tested :)`

Comment: still didnt work. i'll check this more at home, since it will be saturday tomorrow, i think i might have missed a thing or two. i ran your code but used xlApp.Run("Greet", "Hello World"); instead of xlApp.Run("ShowDict", dict); and it ran, but when the code reached your xlApp.Run("ShowDict", dict);, the exception i mentioned occured. i thought it was something about Trust options but the xlApp.Run("Greet", "Hello World");  just ran fine.